# Conditional Expectation and Conditional Variance of three normal variables

Tags: probability, probability-distributions

$u$ is a normally distributed variable with mean $m$ and variance ${s_1}^2$, $y_1=u+e_1$, $y_2=u+e_1+e_2$ where $e_1$ and $e_2$ are independently and normally distributed with zero means and variances equal to ${s_2}^2$ and ${s_3}^2$. How do I show $$\mathbb E\left(u\mid y_1\right)=\mathbb E\left(u \mid y_1, y_2\right)$$ and $$\operatorname{var}\left(u\mid y_1\right)=\operatorname{var}\left(u\mid y_1, y_2\right)?$$ Thanks a lot.

Comment: By "$\mathbb E\left(\dfrac{u}{y_1}, y_2\right)$ do you mean the conidtional expecation of $\dfrac{u}{y_1}$ given $y_2$?  And where you wrote $s_3^3$, might you have intended $s_3^2$? ${}\qquad{}$

Comment: Sorry about my messy notation. I don't know how to type conditional expectations. I meant the conditional expectation of u given y1 is equal to the conditional expectation of u given both y1 and y2. Then the same for the conditional variances too. Yes, I meant a square instead of a cubic. Thanks a lot for your attention and again sorry for my messy notation. This is my first time here.

Comment: I got it worked out by using the conditional mean and variance of a multivariate normal distribution. Thanks a lot.